# "sudo: no password was provided" when running an Ansible module with `local_action`

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I'm trying to use [this `github_key` community module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/github_key_module.html) to add an SSH publickey to a Github account.

(I installed the community module with `ansible-galaxy collection install community.general`)

In my task list, I -

1. Read the `publickey`
2. Call `github_key` (with `local_action`) to add that key to the Github account

```yaml
- name: Read SSH key for jeeves@github.com
  shell: 'cat /home/jeeves/.ssh/jeeves@github.com.pub'
  register: ssh_pub_key

- name: Upload SSH key for jeeves@github.com
  local_action:
    module: github_key
    name: 'Key for jeeves@my-server.dev'
    token: '{{ github_token }}'
    pubkey: '{{ ssh_pub_key.stdout }}'
    force: yes
```

When I run it get this error (in `module_stderr` output):

```
[sudo via ansible, key=<REDACTED>] password:
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

I guess it can't find my `sudo` password for the user.

But I *am* providing a `sudo` password, and there are 30+ other tasks before this (not shown here) where it was able to successfully execute commands. In fact in my playbook definition I use `become`:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: yes
  #...
```

I think the issue is caused by `local_action` since it's having trouble even executing the module itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up figuring this one out?

Comment: I'm curious as well — seeing the same thing in my new environment